# Debian Jessie - Apache2 / PHP 5.6, can't upload more than 128kb

Tags: php, upload, apache2, debian

I've got a problem which is bugging me like crazy! I've recently updated my server to Jessie (wishing I hadn't at the moment!) but ever since I did, I can't upload more than 128KB in a single upload.

I've tried all the usual obvious options - checking php.ini for max file size, execution times, etc but with no solution.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir = /var/tmp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 500M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 50
```

Above is an excerpt from my php.ini files for CLI, CGI and apache2.

I can't think what else to check. If I try and upload anything larger than that, I either get a 500 response from the server or I get a "server unexpectedly dropped connection" error from my web browser. The issue means that if I upload via WordPress I get "HTTP Error" and if I try and upload via Owncloud I get "connection closed".

Debian Jessie
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.6-2 OpenSSL/ 1.0.1k

Apache2 error log looks like this...

```
[Fri Mar 27 11:32:18.736845 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6012] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.6-2 OpenSSL/1.0.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 27 11:32:18.736959 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6012] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:33.881783 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6012] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:34.861896 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6699] AH01906: xxx:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:34.862153 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 6699] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:34.938830 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6701] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:35.051083 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6701] AH01906: xxx:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:35.081620 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6701] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.6-2 OpenSSL/1.0.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 27 11:45:35.081693 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6701] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:41.650574 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6701] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:42.911897 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7255] AH01906: xxx:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:42.912493 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 7255] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:42.983533 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7257] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:43.238951 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7257] AH01906: xxx:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:43.273995 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7257] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.6-2 OpenSSL/1.0.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 27 11:56:43.274080 2015] [core:notice] [pid 7257] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Has anyone had any ideas or come across a similar problem?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/apache-and-php-limits-and-timeouts

> When using PHP-FCGI (a separate PHP process ran via Apache’s mod_fcgid), [mod_fcgid caps uploads to 128KB by default](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) in newer versions (v2.3.6 and above), and usually returns a “500 Server Error” when that limit is reached.

Comment: Excellent thank you. For those who might be having the same problem, you need to add:
FcgidMaxRequestLen 268435456
FcgidBusyTimeout 300
to your fcgid config file. In my case, it was in /etc/apache2/mods-available under fcgid.conf. Add those two lines and restart apache - that should do it. 
Ensure you set your max request length to equal your max php upload size - the amount shown above is 256MB. 
Thanks again dafyk, much appreciated!